# Run an action in a bootstrap script after ResourceManager has started

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I am starting an AWS EMR cluster using the amazon aws cli tools. I have a boostrap action that runs on the master and runs the following command

```
    hdfs dfs -put /home/hadoop/X.tar.gz /
```

However I get the following error

```
    put: Call From X.internal/X1 to X.internal:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

However, once the cluster is up (this error does not cause the startup to fail), i can run the above command successfully.

How can i run hdfs commands in the bootstrap script?

Answer (score 1):

Run it as step, not an action. See the example here:      http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html